# Can cookie data be modified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am setting up a web-app with a login system. I have gotten to a point where my login is working fine and I'm redirecting the user to the controller which is only accessible if the user has been authorized. I need to somehow pass the username to that controller from the publicly accessible controller. I have thought of two ways of doing it:

RedirectAction with username being passed -> is displayed in the browser on login, doesn't scream security to me

Taking it from the cookie. Is this secure? Can the user somehow modify the cookie to become someone else?

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can always use Session to securely store information. The user cannot modify this data.

Second, depending on how you are performing authentication, if you are using a framework then it is probably accessible in the static Request.User object.